# On what parameter does python differentiate between a formatted string and a normal string?

Tags: python, string

```
x = f"There are {n} types of people"

print(type(x)==type("HELLO")) #returns True
```

If the formatted string and a normal string are of same type. How does a function differentiate when to format it or when not to?

My guess is whenever I specify `f` before a string, the interpreter picks up the value of the variables and formats it then and there and function recieves a formatted string.

Is it a shorthand notation just like lambdas in Java 8?

Comment: See [PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/): "It should be noted that an f-string is really an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value."

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your expectation here, you thought that f-strings would create a new type or class of string? why?

Comment: I thought a function can take only one object at a time. So, I don't know why I assumed that it should be a new type (coming from Java and C++). The concept of an interpreter is new to me. So, I felt it should be resolved at "compile time" as a new type and evaluated at runtime. @Chris_Rands

Comment: That compile type might have given a new object which will be formatted at runtime kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  your example:

```
x = f"There are {n} types of people"
```

`x` is never an f-string, it is simply a regular string, already having had the `{n}` replaced by the value of the variable `n`.

An f-string is evaluated syntactically and the resulting object type is `str`.

Comment: On a side note - Is f-string formatting a proper superset of all kinds of formatting?

Comment: @TarunMaganti: No.  For example, `datetime.datetime.strftime()` is a kind of formatting which f-strings do not support.

Answer (score 1):

From [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#abstract):

> F-strings provide a way to embed expressions inside string literals, using a minimal syntax. *It should be noted that an f-string is really an expression evaluated at run time, not a constant value. In Python source code, an f-string is a literal string, prefixed with 'f', which contains expressions inside braces. The expressions are replaced with their values*.

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

They are the same type.

```
n = 5
f"There are {n} types of people"
```

is just a new nice way to insert variables into a string, introduced in Python 3.6

This could also be written like

```
n = 5
"There are {:d} types of people".format(n)
```